# What should I do about old cables that have been damaged?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I was replacing some drywall and noticed the wiring underneath has a couple of surface tears. House is from the sixties, but has been rewired with new Romex, except this circuit. Wire seems to be old type of Romex (cloth covered) and has the marking "HATFLEX NM 14/2". Only the cloth is partially teared-up.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Should I be worried about this? I was considering putting some electrical tape over the damaged sections. Is this ok? What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Repair

You can use a cable jacket repair tape, to repair the jacket. I would not use simple electrical tape to make the repair, since it has a tendency to dry out and fall off.

[Scotch® Cable Jacket Repair Tape 2234](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/EMDCI/Home/Products/Catalog/~/Scotch-Cable-Jacket-Repair-Tape-2234-2-in-x-6-ft?N=4294671545+5427538&Nr=AND(hrcy_id:NK3W3HWR2Sgs_7T837C4WSC_N2RL3FHWVK_GPD0K8BC31gv)&rt=d)

[image: Scotch® Cable Jacket Repair Tape 2234]

> ### Repairing Damaged Cable Jacket When No Portion of Cable Jacket is Missing
>
> - Abrade the cable jacket 3" (75 mm) beyond each side of the damaged cable jacket section
>     [image: figure 1]
> - Wrap one half-lapped layer of Scotch® Cable Jacket Repair Tape 2234 extending at least 2" (50 mm) on each side beyond the damaged cable jacket
>     [image: figure 2]
> - Starting 1" (25 mm) past the Scotch® Cable Jacket Repair Tape 2234, apply 3 half-lapped layers of [Scotch™ Super 33+™ Vinyl Electrical Tape](http://www.3m.com/product/information/Scotch-Super-33plus-Vinyl-Electrical-Tape.html) to each end to temporarily secure the ends of the Scotch® 2234 tape to the cable jacket until the tape reaches full bond.
>     [image: figure 3]
>
> [Instructions](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/mediawebserver?mwsId=SSSSSufSevTsZxtUo8_S58t1evUqevTSevTSevTSeSSSSSS--&fn=78-8129-9497-4.pdf)

<sup>***NOTE:*** Other products do exist.  The products listed above are for example purposes only. I do not recommend or endorse the above listed products.</sup>

## Replace

If the section is accessible at both ends, you could simply replace the section of cable.